# Modal carregando iframe antes de serem abertos

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estou implementando em um portal vários links iframe nos modals. Alguns chegam ter o primeiro modal com vários ícones para entrar para o próximo modal com o iframe (modal sobre modal). Quando comecei a implementar estava funcionando tudo bem, mais depois percebi que começou a dar problema porque quando entro na pagina principal os iframes ficam pré-carregados nos modals. E quando entro nos modals com iframes eles não respondem as requisições do iframe original.

```
<a href="#despesas" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#despesas" target="" class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center home">
    <img src="icones/icone_despesas.png" alt="Despesas" />
</a>

<!--  ICONES SUBMENU - DESPESAS-->
<div class="modal fade" id="despesas">
    <div class="modal-layout">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" class="blank" title="Fechar" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Despesas</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
```

Aqui tenho varios icones dentro no body do primeiro mdoal chamando cada modal com uma iframe:

```
<!--  ICONE Despesas por credor    OK-->            
              <a data-toggle="modal" role="button" data-target="#despesascredor">
              <img src="icones/sub_menus/icone_despesas_credor.png" alt="Despesa" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center sub"/>
              </a>
```

Já aqui eu deixo a reposta para a chamada com o iframe:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="despesascredor" data-remote= >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" class="blank" title="Fechar" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Despesas por credor</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
            <iframe id= "iframe_betha" src="LINK" />
 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ai quando entro na pagina, o site fica muito tempo carregando os iframes para deixarem pré carregados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha solução foi a seguinte:

1° Criei o `modal` normal, e onde eu queria colocar o `iframe` que no caso era no `modal-body` deixei somente assim:

```
<iframe/>
```

Obs. Talvez precise ajustar a janela com `width height frameborder`

2° Ai no javaScript que vem o segredo:

```
  $('#MyModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#MyModal iframe').attr('src','LINK EXTERNO E INTERNO');
})
  $('#MyModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#MyModal iframe').removeAttr('src');
})
```

Supriu perfeitamente minhas necessidades.